# How do I get each child process to output a string?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

For my assignment, I'm expected to "have the children generate a, b, c, & time it and then have them generate multiples of each letter to see concurrency in action.  Use nested loops to go up to, say 500 of each letter."

Currently, my `letter_generator.exe` program just randomly chooses a letter and prints said letter. My program (mostly my professor's I just added a few things) below creates `1500` child processes which isn't at all what I believe the assignment wants me to do. So, my question is how do I get each child process to print a specific letter?

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;

int main(VOID){
  STARTUPINFO si;
  PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

  // allocate memory
  ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
  si.cb = sizeof(si);
  ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));
  
  volatile int i = 0;
  auto start = chrono::steady_clock::now();

  int const CHILD_PROCESS_LIMIT = 1500;
  for (i = 0; i < CHILD_PROCESS_LIMIT; i++){
      // create child process
    if (!CreateProcess(NULL, // use command line
      "C:\\Users\\Coughing\\Desktop\\letter_generator.exe", // app name
      NULL,  // don't inherit process handle
      NULL,  // don't inherit thread handle
      FALSE, // disable handle inheritance
      0,     // no creation flags
      NULL,  // use parent's environment block
      NULL,  // use parent's existing directory
      &si,
      &pi)){
        fprintf(stderr, "create process failed");
        return -1;
      }
  } 

  // parent waits for child to complete
  WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
  
  auto end = chrono::steady_clock::now();
  chrono::duration<double> elapsed_seconds = end - start;

  cout << "Children Complete in " << elapsed_seconds.count() << " seconds!";

  // close handles
  CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
  CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
}
```

Comment: First, stick the `WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);` inside of the `for` loop after the `if` statement. After `WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);` make sure to call `CloseHandle` on that opened process. Currently you're starting the process and then not waiting for it to complete. You're also not closing 1499 of the `handles` you're opening.

Comment: Actually you're not closing 2998 of the handles you're opening.

Comment: @WBuck - if he will wait for the process to finish inside the loop - where is the concurrency???

Comment: @VladFeinstein You'll have to keep track of each process you're opening which currently you're not doing. You'll have to store the handles in a container and then use `WaitForMultipleObjects` to wait for all of the processes to complete. Or use IOCP but let's not get into anything overly complex like that.

Comment: @WBuck - exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a basic example of starting a child process and passing it an argument via the command line.

I'll leave the remainder of your homework for you to figure out.

Also note I'm using some `C++17` features here, so if you can't compile either set the language standard in Visual Studio to `C++17` or change the code to compile for the version of standard you're using.

#### Parent Process

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>
#include <Windows.h>

int main( )
{
    std::cout << "Opening processes\n";

    for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) 
    {
        STARTUPINFO startup_info{ };
        PROCESS_INFORMATION process_info{ };

        // To pass arguments to the child process replace 'test'
        // with whatever argument you want to pass.
        std::wstring args{ L"Child.exe test" };

        // create child process
        if( !CreateProcessW( 
            LR"(C:\Path\Child.exe)", // use command line
            args.data( ),
            nullptr,  // don't inherit process handle
            nullptr,  // don't inherit thread handle
            false,    // disable handle inheritance
            0,        // no creation flags
            nullptr,  // use parent's environment block
            nullptr,  // use parent's existing directory
            &startup_info,
            &process_info ) ) 
        {
            std::error_code ec{ static_cast<int>( 
                GetLastError( ) ), std::system_category( ) };

            std::cerr << "Failed to start process: " << ec.message( ) << '\n';
            return -1;
        }

        std::cout << "Waiting for process to complete\n";

        auto start{ std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now( ) };

        if( auto code{ WaitForSingleObject( 
            process_info.hProcess, INFINITE ) }; code != WAIT_OBJECT_0 )
        {
            std::error_code ec{ static_cast<int>(
                GetLastError( ) ), std::system_category( ) };

            std::cerr << "Failed to wait for process: " << ec.message( ) << '\n';
        }

        auto elapsed{ std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now( ) - start };
        auto duration{ std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>( elapsed ) };

        std::cout << "Time: " << duration.count( ) << " us\n";

        CloseHandle( process_info.hProcess );
        CloseHandle( process_info.hThread );
    }
}
```

#### Child Process

```
#include <iostream>

int main( int argc, char* argv[ ] )
{
    if( argc > 1 )
    {
        // The argument we passed will be located at index
        // 1 in argv.
        auto arg{ argv[ 1 ] };
        // Prints 'test'.
        std::cout << "Argument: " << arg << '\n';
    }
}
```